# Can express.static be used on a server with private files?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a pretty basic express.js server in which I have created a `private` folder to go along with the `public` folder. All requests starting with `/private` are served static files from that folder as long as they have the proper authorization headers. Otherwise they are redirected and served files from the `public` folder. So here is the basic setup:

Folder structure:

```
-root
--- public
--- private
```

`app.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/private', requireAuth, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private')));
```

I am wondering if there is any way for the user to go 'up one' directory from the `public` folder to gain access to files from the `private` folder, which would completely defeat my security measures. In other words, is it safe to serve arbitrary static files from *any* directory on a server where some directories are meant to be private?

Comment: With `__dirname` it is save. %)P

Comment: As per your directory structure, no one can access your private directory's files without authorise unlike public, assume that if that is possible to go back one directory then any body can access our code(app.js, config files, etc.) but that is not possible